# What are the newest AWS service's versions for Gradle?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, gradle, build.gradle, version-numbering

Those who have read the [official AWS documentation for android](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html) will understand the issue at first glance. In brief, AWS says to integrate their services using the `build.gradle` in your project. However, for the version numbers they tell you to fill in a "`+`" at the end of the number.

For example, you have to type `com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.+` in `build.gradle` to use AWS lambda. This makes Android Studio highlight the line in yellow and give a message saying `Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable builds(com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.+)`.

The warning message has lead me to believe there should be an accurate version number, instead of just typing in a `+`. If anyone could tell me the accurate version numbers of...

1) Autoscaling

2) Cloudwatch

3) DynamoDB

4) EC2

5) Mobile Analytics

6) S3

7) SNS

...I would be really grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you watch the [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-android-sdk-lambda) you can see, that the newest version is 2.3.0.

Comment: My answer was for the original question for aws-android-sdk-lambda.
For all other modules you can simply use the [maven repository search](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=SNS).

Or you use [jcenters search](https://bintray.com/search?query=DynamoDB)

Comment: the versions for all services in aws sdk for android are always in sync. So your answer 2.3.0 is valid for all other modules as well.